# MySQL Count within an IF

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, count, conditional-statements

```mysql
+-------------+--------------+----------+-------+
| ticketRefNo | nameOnTicket | boughtBy | event |
+-------------+--------------+----------+-------+
|          38 | J XXXXXXXXX  |        2 |    13 |
|          39 | C YYYYYYY    |        1 |    13 |
|          40 | M ZZZZZZZZZZ |        3 |    14 |
|          41 | C AAAAAAA    |        3 |    15 |
|          42 | D BBBBBB     |        3 |    16 |
|          43 | A CCCCC      |        3 |    17 |
+-------------+--------------+----------+-------+

+-------------+------------------+--------------+---------------------+--------+
| ticketRefNo | cardNo           | cardHolder   | exp                 | issuer |
+-------------+------------------+--------------+---------------------+--------+
|          38 | 4444111133332222 | J McKenny    | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | BOS    |
|          39 | 4434111133332222 | C Dempsey    | 2016-04-01 00:00:00 | BOS    |
|          40 | 4244111133332222 | M Gunn-Davis | 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | RBS    |
+-------------+------------------+--------------+---------------------+--------+

+-------------+-------------+----------+
| ticketRefNo | boxOfficeID | paidWith |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
|          41 |           1 | card     |
|          42 |           2 | cash     |
|          43 |           3 | chequ    |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
```

I have a database with the data shown above. It represents a ticket-buying system. I would like to be able to see a list of tickets bought with the name of the event and either the boxOfficeID or the issuer of the debit card.

I have tried running the following code, to no avail.

```
SELECT t.ticketRefNo AS 'Reference', t.event AS 'Event', 
IF(COUNT(SELECT * FROM Online WHERE t.ticketRefNo=o.ticketRefNo;) >= 1,
o.issuer, InPerson.boxOfficeID) AS 'Card Issuer or Box Office'
FROM Ticket AS t, InPerson, Online AS o 
WHERE t.ticketRefNo=o.ticketRefNo;
```

Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Some notes: the semicolon character isn't valid syntax; if you have a need to delimit the subquery, wrap it in parens.  Escape column aliases like you'd escape any other identifier: use backticks, not single quotes. Single quotes are used around string literals.

Assuming that `issuer` in the `Online` table is NOT NULL, and assuming that `ticketRefNo` is unique in both the `Online` and `InPerson` tables, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT t.ticketRefNo    AS `Reference`
     , t.event          AS `Event`
     , IF(o.ticketRefNo IS NOT NULL,o.issuer,i.boxOfficeId) 
       AS `Card Issuer or Box Office`
  FROM Ticket t
  LEFT
  JOIN InPerson i 
    ON i.ticketRefNo = t.ticketRefNo
  LEFT
  JOIN Online o
    ON o.ticketRefNo  = t.ticketRefNo
```

Use outer join operations to find matching rows in the `InPerson` and `Online` tables, and use a conditional test to see if you got a matching row from the `Online` table. A NULL will be returned if there wasn't a matching row found.

Comment: Good answer. You can simplify this a little with coalesce: `COALESCE(o.issuer, i.boxOfficeId) AS ...`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to have one column JOINing to two different tables with some values in each of the two tables.

But here goes anyway:

```
( SELECT ... FROM Ticket t JOIN InPerson x USING(ticketRefNo) ... )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... FROM Ticket t JOIN Online x USING(ticketRefNo) ... )
ORDER BY ...
```

The `ALL` assumes that InPerson and Online never have any overlapping ticketRefNos.
The ORDER BY an the end is in case you want to sort things, although I see no need for it in your attempted SELECT.
The two SELECTs must have the same number of columns.

Comment: Straight forward and easy to read. Good answer. You may have to cast in order to get the same column type.